# Is there any free version for Telerik ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc

I'm going to develop ASP.NET MVC 4 using VS2012.I heard that Telerik released some free version for Telerik MVC 4.I search everywhere but i couldn't find out.Anyone had a experience on it ?

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/general/telerik-mvc-extensions-resources.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a version of Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC 4. However you can use the ASP.NET MVC 3 version without any problems. You need to add the following binding redirects to your web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <!--... elements deleted for clarity ...-->
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```